# What exactly is the airspace above CYYZ (Toronto)?

Tags: airport, airspace, transport-canada

I'm [planning my first real life cross country trip from KFRG to CYKZ](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47961/62). I'm trying to understand the Toronto Airspace:

1. Is a Canadian Class C airspace the same as a US Class B airspace?
2. Toronto Pearson International (CYYZ) inner blue circle has this marking 125/25 and the number 25 within a broken square bracket:

[image]

I believe this means that the airspace above CYYZ is broken into two parts: class B and class C. Does anyone know the reason for this? I have not seen this structure in the US.

3. The sectional for this area has the following note:

> TORONTO CLASS C AIRSPACE FOR FLIGHTS BELOW AT AND BELOW 12500' MSL SEE
>   TORONTO VTA CHART

I actually purchased a Toronto VFR Terminal Area (VTA) chart but it's even more confusing than the normal sectional. What exactly am I looking for on the chart?

Comment: Instead of deleting your other question and just adding details in a new question, please [edit it](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/47962/edit) instead.

Comment: @RonBeyer I didn't delete my other question. Both questions are still available. I just posted two separate questions because I thought putting so many questions in one question won't be wise.

Comment: Before you try to hop in VFR to a busy Class-B like CYYZ, give them a call (on the phone) to figure out the best time to arrive and the arrival method they would prefer. Nothing ticks off Class-B controllers like trying to squeeze a Cessna 172 into a busy traffic pattern unannounced. It is a little different for IFR flights, they may downright refuse to let you in VFR, so have a backup plan if they don't let you in.

Comment: @RonBeyer This is good advice. Entering Class B is not my primary option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canadian Class C airspace is generally the same as US Class C airspace. Prior permission is required before entering. Canadian Class B airspace is 12,500' and above. Not a factor for you most likely.

I recommend reading the VFR legend to better understand the markings. It's all there if you purchased a map. The 125/25 marking is the ceiling and floor of the airspace. What you're looking at is the US Sectional, not the Canadian one however. The square [25] refers to the control zone around the airport. You won't be landing in Pearson, so you definitely won't be in their control zone. It extends about 8nm from the airport from surface to 2500' and most busy airports have one. All control zones are class C airspace.

What you're looking for on the VTA is VFR planning. It will have recommended routes to follow, as well warnings and information needed to be able to plan a VFR flight through the area.